# Python deleting a repo from github with request module

Tags: python, django, api, github, repository

I do not coding a this situation.
I can create a repository in python using a `request.post()`, but I can not delete a this repository.

Here is the code:

```
    def deleteRepository(self, repo, name):
    headers = {'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
                'Authorization': 'token {}'.format(self.token)}
    response = requests.delete(self.api_url + '/repos/' + name + repo, headers = headers)
    return response.json()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+ name + repo` seems strange.

Consider [this implementation](https://github.com/metinoguzhan/python_bastan_sona_sadik_turan/blob/a70ce867c1e737ec05c62f8dbae2b47e1955155e/14_Python_Advanced_Moduls_Web_Scraping/08_github-demo.py#L28-L30) for instance

```py
def deleteRepository(self,name,username):
        response = requests.delete(self.api_url+'/repos/' + username + '/'+name+'?access_token='+self.token)
        print(response.status_code)
```

Note the `'/repos/' + username + '/'+name+'` part: separators are important for your [path segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#path).

---

Update June 2021: as explained in "
[Deprecating API authentication through query parameters](https://developer.github.com/changes/2/#/changes/2020-02-10-deprecating-auth-through-query-param/) "

> If you're currently making an API call similar to
>
> ```
> curl "https://api.github.com/user/repos?access_token=my_access_token"
> ```
>
> Instead, you should send the token in the header:
>
> ```
> curl -H 'Authorization: token my_access_token' https://api.github.com/user/repos
> ```

So:

```py
def deleteRepository(self,name,username):
        response = requests.delete(self.api_url+'/repos/' + username + '/'+name+', headers={'Authorization': 'token self.token'})
        print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: I did as you said and the problem is solved. Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you test it? `..Must specify access token via Authorization header...changes/2020-02-10-deprecating`

Comment: @Timo It worked at the time, but maybe: https://developer.github.com/changes/2/#removal-date or rather https://developer.github.com/changes/2/#removal

Comment: @Timo I have edited the answer accordingly.